Linear regression MLE of slope; OLS and bivariate MLE
Assume the variables X and Y, sampled from a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector $(\mu, \mu)$,and both having the same population variance $V$, which is known. The only unknown parameter is $\rho$.
The sample only contains X values below a known cutoff $c$, which is less than $\mu$ and the corresponding $Y$ values. Therefore sample means and variances are different from the true (and known) population mean and variance.

Would it be correct to frame this a linear regression problem with the model $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon $ and since the variances are the same, take $\rho = \beta_1$?

The OLS estimator, minimizing $(y - \mu) - \beta_1(x - \mu) $ happens to be $\Sigma (x_i - \mu)(y_i - \mu)/\Sigma (x_i - \mu)^2 $ the same is obtained by MLE assuming residuals $(y_i - \mu) - \beta_1(x_i - \mu) $ are normally distributed with zero mean and fixed variance.

Is it possible to use MLE for the original bivariate distribution with known means and SDs to estimate $\rho$? I tried to obtain the estimate but it contained cubic expression of $\rho$ which I couldn't solve. On simulations, MLE for bivariate is not exactly the same. Are these methods equivalent?

Update:
Mechanism of truncation: $X$ is a measurement of a biochemical parameter. A repeat measurement $(Y)$ was made, only when $X$ was below the cutoff $c$. Assuming the first measurement did not affect the second measurement, I want to estimate the unbiased correlation between them using this truncated data-pairs.

Please explain what you mean by a "truncated set of observations."  A "truncated set" sounds like an ordinary set--a sample.  What's special about that?  Or are you trying to say the observations are truncated in some sense?  If so, what?

@whuber , What I meant by truncated set, is a sample as you mentioned, but not selected randomly. The sample only contains values less than a cutoff as the Y variable, and the corresponding X values. I corrected it in the question.

Therefore sample means are different from the true mean (which is known), and sample correlation coefficient is biased.

Please include those explanations in the question, which currently does not describe the form of truncation you refer to.  That's crucial information!

@whuber added them in the question.

Thank you.  The question is still ambiguous: what is the mechanism causing all values to have $Y$ less than the threshold?

The assumptions underlying the OLS estimator of $\rho$ based on regressing $Y$ on $X$ would apply only if $X$ is truncated rather than $Y$ (you have it the other way around in your question).

@JarleTufto thank you, that was my mistake, it was corrected.

@whuber the mechanism of obtaining the sample was added as an update.

Yes, I noticed: +1.  It's an interesting question.

When all parameters other than $\rho$ are known, the full likelihood $L(\rho)$ based on the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is equal to the likelihood $L_R(\rho)$ associated with the regression of $Y$ on $X$ up to a constant of proportionality that does not depend on $\rho$ since
$$
L(\rho)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i,y_i|\rho)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)f(y_i|x_i,\rho)\propto \prod_{i=1}^n f(y_i|x_i,\rho)=L_R(\rho)
$$ since the truncated marginal density of each $x_i$ does not depend on $\rho$.  So you loose no information about $\rho$ by treating the problem as a simple regression.  And the estimator based on OLS is known to be a minimum variance unbiased estimator.

Thank you. Does that mean, that maximizing the full likelihood and the likelihood associated with regression should both get the same estimate for $\rho$? If so is it possible to show this mathematically?

Yes, this follows since the two likelihoods are proportional.

Based on the regression likelihood, $\prod_{i=1}^n f(Y_i|X_i, \rho) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 X_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$
since $\beta_0 = \mu(1 - \beta_1)$
setting the derivative with respect to beta to zero would get
$\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - (\mu - \beta_1\mu) - \beta_1X_i)(-X_i + \mu) = 0$
$\beta_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \mu)(X_i - \mu)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2} = \rho$
How to show this is equivalent to the MLE of $L(\rho|\sigma^2, \sigma^2,X, Y) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i, Y_i)$

@supun Do you agree that $f(x_i,y_i \mid \rho) = f(x_i)f(y_i|x_i,\rho)$ where the marginal density $f(x_i)$ of $x_i$ does not depend on $\rho$?  Given this, is it clear that the likelihoods are proportional and so doing inference based on either likelihood must clearly produce the same MLE of $\rho$.

Yes I agree, the problem was, I was getting slightly different answers. I treated variance in the conditional likelihood a constant, when it actually is a function of $\rho$ and the MLE I derived in the question seems not correct and fixing this gave the same answer for both full likelihood and regression likelihood as you pointed out.
Still the OLS estimator I get is the same as mentioned in the question. Does this mean OLS estimator is different in this case tho MLE, or did I make mistake in OLS derivation by minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i - (\beta x_i + \mu(1-\beta))\right)$.
